# Add command-line to USB unbind udev rule

Tags: arch-linux, usb, udev

I'm executing this command line from my user session:

```
echo '1-1.4' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

which is perfectly working. How can I do an `udev rule` (which applies it at startup)? My file which is going to contain the `udev rule` to do it is at `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-disable-usb.rules`.

Comment: just as an FYI, there's no need to "sudo echo ..."

Comment: @JeffSchaller `sudo` was superfluous, evidently not the same thing for `echo` .

Comment: Right; sorry, I didn't emphasize the *sudo* part